# Why wont these potions display their names and lore?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Here is the potions in question; I'm spawning them in a shulker box:

{Slot:16,id:splash_potion ,display:{Name:"E.N.D",Lore:["BOOK OF ZAREFF SHADOW DRAGON FORCE!!"]},Count:64,tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[ {                            Id: 6,                            Amplifier: 125,                            Duration: 199980                       }]}},                 {Slot:17,id:splash_potion,Count:64,tag:{CustomPotionEffects:[ {                                                      Id: 3,                            Amplifier: 5,                            Duration: 1999980                        },                        {                            Id: 5,                            Amplifier: 100,                            Duration: 1999980                        },                        {                            Id: 10,                            Amplifier: 100,                            Duration: 1999980                        },                        {                            Id: 11,                            Amplifier: 100,                            Duration: 1999980                        },                        {                            Id: 12,                            Amplifier: 100,                            Duration: 1999980                        },                        {                            Id: 13,                            Amplifier: 100,                            Duration: 1999980                                      },

Comment: Figured it out without u

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the `display` compound inside the `CustomPotionEffects` list, you need it after it (on the same level).

Comment: so I fixed it and its still not showing up

Comment: Then you didn't fix it, update the post with your "fixed" command.

Comment: Edited Let me know if I did it wrong

Comment: display is still inside the CustomPotionEffects list.

Comment: alright I will move it around some more

Comment: So Its no longer in the custompotions list but still no name

Comment: It still needs to be inside the tag compound:

{Slot:,id:,tag:{display:{Name:""},CustomPotionEffects:[{},{},{}]}}